# TSQL Find and Replace in String

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have a table that I use for error logging when inserts fail on the front end of my site. It stores the params URL as a text string so we can see what values were sent over and why it may have failed.

Well I am now working with this data to try and recover some records from it.

This is what the record looks like in my field:

```
xml=&lt;data&gt;&lt;optional&gt;&lt;Account&gt;192070041&lt;/Account&gt;&lt;/optional&gt;&lt;/data&gt;, submitter=Q1370, target=Q1234, escalationType=esc, escalationReason=277, feedback=cx req live esc to have us release his alh payment for 8487.18, adv cx his funds are eligble for release on july 2nd at 445 pm est, preventable=0,
```

The issue I am running into recovering some data is that on a script I am writing in PHP, I am getting all of the params individualy by exploding on the `= sign` to get each of the values.

Well, the `feedback=` section happens to be comments that contains commas and its messing up a lot of stuff.

What I need to do is within the string, I need to find everything in `feedback=xxxxxxxxxx,` and either remove all the commas from that section or replace with with a `|` pipe so I can just change them back later.

My lack of knowledge in this area is where I hope some one can point me in the right direction so I can get some records restored on a mass level.

Example: 
Before String - `param1=dfsfsf, param2=fdsfsdfds, param3=bob, how are you doing today?`
After String -  `param1=dfsfsf, param2=fdsfsdfds, param3=bob| how are you doing today?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE YourTable SET URL=REPLACE(URL,',','|')
```

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181984.aspx

**Later edit**: I read your question more carefully and I now understand that you want to replace only the commas in after a certain substring. Try something like this:

```
DECLARE @URL NVARCHAR(1000)
SET @URL='Before String - param1=dfsfsf, param2=fdsfsdfds, param3=bob, how are you doing today?'

SELECT LEFT(@URL,ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX('param3=',@URL),0),LEN(@URL)))
    +ISNULL(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(@URL,NULLIF(CHARINDEX('param3=',@URL),0),1000),',','|'),'')
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't think you fully understand the question.